# Doctrine Proxie generation

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

Hi I am unable to generate my proxies using php doctrine orm:generate-proxies

Here is the XML file that I am using: application/entities/xml/Beacon.Entities.Center.dcm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Beacon\Entities\Center" table="center">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="250" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="street" type="string" column="street" length="250" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="suburb" type="string" column="suburb" length="250" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="city" type="string" column="city" length="250" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="centerId" type="integer" column="center_id" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="unsigned"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="dateCreated" type="datetime" column="date_created" nullable="true"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

This is the class that is being used: application/entities/Center.php

```
<?php

namespace Beacon\Entities;

/**
 * Beacon\Entities\Center
 */
class Center
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $suburb;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $centerId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Center
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     *
     * @return Center
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * Set suburb
     *
     * @param string $suburb
     *
     * @return Center
     */
    public function setSuburb($suburb)
    {
        $this->suburb = $suburb;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get suburb
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSuburb()
    {
        return $this->suburb;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return Center
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set centerId
     *
     * @param integer $centerId
     *
     * @return Center
     */
    public function setCenterId($centerId)
    {
        $this->centerId = $centerId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get centerId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCenterId()
    {
        return $this->centerId;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     *
     * @return Center
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I have tried renaming the classes without namespace to no avail. I seem to get this error whatever I try.

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  Class 'Beacon\Entities\Center' does not exist

Comment: it seems like an autoloading problem. Is your class autoloaded? Do you use composer autoloading? Do you use psr-0/psr-4 autoloading and is you class in correct directory structure?

Comment: I find this hard to believe as I have managed to generate the for two of the entities that are in the same file structure

Comment: When i set the entities to auto generate then it generates fine. However when I try generate the proxies manually I get the above error

Comment: what happens when you try to have them autogenerated? [http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#auto-generating-proxy-classes-optional]. or when you try with different enviroment `php doctrine orm:generate-proxies --env=prod` .. also try to debug with removing all fields but one in the entity

Comment: try with the enviroment settings, as autogeneration will pickup the correct env, but using the CLI you need to explicitly set it.

Comment: Auto generation is perfect no issues there only with manual

Comment: Try with the enviroment settings, as autogeneration will pickup the correct env, but using the CLI you need to explicitly set it. – nakashu yesterday. Could you tell me what variables to change

Comment: `php doctrine orm:generate-proxies --env=prod`